# Weird behaviour of import tag in spring's configuration file

Tags: spring

I am working on the spring spring-3.2.2. I have created two java projects in eclipse.

1. SpringTest
2. Testclasspath

SpringTest project is having the below beans.xml in which the one bean is defined.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.spring.HelloWorld" init-method="testUpdate" scope="prototype">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

I have created the jar springtest.jar of the project SpringTest and it is been added in the classpath of the project Testclasspath. Bean configuration file for the Testclasspath project is talentacquisition.xml and it is importing the beans.xml file of the Springtest project. Please find the below content of talentacquisition.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="Beans.xml"/>
    <bean id="juggler" class="com.springaction.springidol.Juggler" />

 </beans>
```

I am confused with behavior of the import tag in the talentacquisition.xml How it is able to locate the Beans.xml which is present in the jar (springtest.jar) in the classpath and able to load the beans? Why spring is not giving any error ? Don't I have to modify the import tag in the talentacqusition.xml to following

```
<import resource="classpath:Beans.xml"/>
```

If import is able to locate the file Beans.xml , then when should we use  **classpath:** and **classpath* :**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourceLoader`s are responsible for how Spring loads the resource. From the reference manual

> The location path or paths supplied to an ApplicationContext
>   constructor are actually resource strings, and in simple form are
>   treated appropriately to the specific context implementation.
>   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext treats a simple location path as a
>   classpath location. You can also use location paths (resource strings)
>   with special prefixes to force loading of definitions from the
>   classpath or a URL, regardless of the actual context type.

The ClassPathXmlApplicationContext you're instantiating "treats a simple location path as a classpath location", i.e. it treats "Beans.xml" as "classpath:Beans.xml". Similarly, FileSystemXmlApplicationContext would treat "Beans.xml" as "file:Beans.xml". 
 Section 6.7 of the manual has more details too.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer Emerson!!!  ApplicationContext constructor I had specified the  talentacquisition.xml which spring is able to load successfully. Please find the code snippet below. ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("talentacquisition.xml");                         But my question is how import tag is able to locate and load the file Beans.xml from the classpath?

Comment: It's basically a shortcut. As the quote says, the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext you're instantiating "treats a simple location path as a classpath location", i.e. it treats "Beans.xml" as "classpath:Beans.xml". Similary, FileSystemXmlApplicationContext would treat "Beans.xml" as "file:Beans.xml".

Comment: But I am not loading the Beans.xml through the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. I am only loading the talentacqusition.xml through the below code snippet.                     ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("talentacquisition.xml");

Comment: Beans.xml is been loaded through the import tag written inside the talenacqusition.xml.                                                    <import resource="Beans.xml"/> Does ClassPathXmlApplicationContext treats import tag written in talentacqusition.xml as  this as below <import resource="classpath:Beans.xml"/> ?

Comment: You're creating one application context, and that's a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. The import tags are used by that context to read the bean definitions in other resources. But a single CPXAContext is doing all the work. So yes, all import tags without a prefix will be treated as "classpath:" imports.